# Block size background image in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FQ7P.png) on my website, but when I zoom with the scroll, the image becomes blurred. So, what I need it is not resize when I zoom.

This is my CSS code:

```
body
{
    margin: 0;
    color: #bbb;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    background-color: #202121;
    background-image: url("img/wild_oliva.png");
    background-size: initial;
}
```

The image must be repeated on the screen.

Comment: try background-repeat: repeat; and give the image some fixed height and width.

Comment: Still not working :(

Comment: The image is supposed to zoom and become blurred because you're zooming everything on the whole page not just the image

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ssd3fexm/

Answer (score 0):

```
body
{
    margin: 0;
    color: #bbb;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    background-color: #202121;
    background-image: url("img/wild_oliva.png");
    background-size: initial;
}
img{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

You might want to try something like this and see if it works.